# tkinter SpinBox: delay between updating displayed value and associated StringVar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Summary: a single click to a tkinter SpinBox arrow increments the number in the GUI, but a check vs. the associated StringVar() for the entry lags behind by a click.

I have created composite widgets, containing numerical entries, that call a Model calculation when an entry change is committed. I don't want to simply call the model every time the entry is changed, because calculations can be slow. So, the actual code uses binding on `<Tab>`, `<Return>`, etc. (omitted from the example code below) and only calls the models on such a 'commit'.

The SpinBox documentation I reviewed didn't reveal a way to bind to the up/down arrow buttons of the SpinBox itself. So, I have bindings for clicking and releasing the mouse button. On click and release, the last stored value is compared to the current StringVar value, and if they are different the stored value is updated and the model is called. The key methods involved are `bind_entry`, `on_press`, `on_release`, `refresh`, `entry_is_changed`,  and `save_entry`. (There is commented-out code in `on_press` and `on_release` that would allow the model to be refreshed as the SpinBox arrow is depressed; it is retained to make the intended final behavior clear, but is not needed to replicate the bug).

```
from tkinter import *  # technically bad practice, but common


class SpinBoxFrame(Frame):
    """
    A tkinter Frame that holds a labeled entry widget with added behavior.
    EntryFrame will call the function (provided as 'model' in the arguments)
    when a change in the entry's value is committed.

    Arguments (in addition to standard Frame options):
        name-- for widget label and introspection
        array-- a 2D array ( list of lists, [[],[]]
        coord-- the coordinate of the array to be read from/written to
        from_, to, increment: SpinBox arguments (minimum and maximum values,
        and incremental change on each arrow click)
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None, name='', model=None,
                 array=None, coord=(0, 0),
                 from_=0.00, to=100.00, increment=1,
                 **options):

        Frame.__init__(self, parent, **options)
        self.name = name
        self.model = model
        self.array = array
        self.row, self.col = coord
        self.spinbox_kwargs = {'from_': from_,
                               'to': to,
                               'increment': increment}
        self.initialize()
        self.add_label()
        self.add_entry()
        self.bind_entry()
        self.validate_entry()

    def initialize(self):
        self.value_var = StringVar()
        self.value = self.array[self.row][self.col]
        self.value_var.set(self.value)

    def add_label(self):
        Label(self, text=self.name, bg='white', bd=0).pack(side=TOP)

    def add_entry(self):
        self.entry = Spinbox(self, width=7,
                             validate='key',  # check for number on keypress
                             **self.spinbox_kwargs)
        self.entry.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.entry.config(textvariable=self.value_var)

    def bind_entry(self):
        self.entry.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda event: self.refresh())
        self.entry.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda event: self.on_press())
        self.entry.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda event: self.on_release())

    def refresh(self):
        if self.entry_is_changed():
            print('VALUE CHANGE')
            self.save_entry()
            print('Saved new ', self.name, ' value')
            self.model()

    def entry_is_changed(self):
        print('Old value of ', self.name, ' was ', self.value)
        print('Current value of ', self.name, ' is ',
              float(self.value_var.get()))
        return self.value != float(self.value_var.get())

    def save_entry(self):
        if not self.value_var.get():  # if entry left blank,
            self.value_var.set(0.00)  # fill it with zero
        self.value = float(self.value_var.get())
        self.array[self.row][self.col] = self.value

    def on_press(self):
        print('Button pressed')
        # self.loop_refresh()  # uncomment to enable real-time refreshing

    def loop_refresh(self):
        self.refresh()
        self.button_held_job = self._root().after(50, self.loop_refresh)

    def on_release(self):
        print('Button released')
        # uncomment if loop enabled in on_press()
        # self._root().after_cancel(self.button_held_job)
        self.refresh()

    def validate_entry(self):
        """
        The base EntryFrame class assumes the entry contents should be numerical
        """
        # check on each keypress if new result will be a number
        self.entry['validatecommand'] = (self.register(self.is_number), '%P')
        # sound 'bell' if bad keypress
        self.entry['invalidcommand'] = 'bell'

    @staticmethod
    def is_number(entry):
        """
        tests to see if entry is acceptable (either empty, or able to be
        converted to a float.)
        """
        if not entry:
            return True  # Empty string: OK if entire entry deleted
        try:
            float(entry)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dummy_array = [[1, 42], [0, 0]]
    root = Tk()


    class TestFrame(Frame):
        """Mimics a toolbar object that holds entry widgets and passes their
        entries on to a model"""
        def __init__(self, parent, **options):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent, **options)

        def call_model(self):
            print('requesting calculation from the model, using:')
            print(dummy_array)

    mainwindow = TestFrame(root)
    mainwindow.pack()

    box1 = SpinBoxFrame(mainwindow, array=dummy_array, coord=(0, 0),
                                 name='Box 1', model=mainwindow.call_model)
    box1.pack(side=LEFT)
    box2 = SpinBoxFrame(mainwindow, array=dummy_array, coord=(0, 1),
                        name='Box 2', model=mainwindow.call_model)
    box2.pack(side=LEFT)

    # workaround fix for Tk problems and mac mouse/trackpad:
    while True:
        try:
            root.mainloop()
            break
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
```

A single click and release of a SpinBox arrow increments/decrements the value in the GUI, but the check vs. StringVar indicates no change. A second click of the same arrow in the same direction results in a change, but to the previous value not the current GUI value. So, the StringVar check always lags behind the displayed value by one. I am wondering if there is some 'race condition' involved in how fast my code runs vs. how fast the tkinter mainloop updates the StringVar object associated with the SpinBox entry. It seems like `entry_is_changed` is being called faster than the StringVar is updated.

The screenshot shows the nature of the bug. First, the left widget was incremented from 1 to 2 by a single click, but the value check still indicates the current StringVar still holds "1". Then, the right widget was incremented twice. After the first increment from 42 to 43, no change in value was seen. After the second increment from 43 to 44, a change to the value 43 was seen.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the `<ButtonRelease-1>` event triggers `refresh` before the update of the variable value. To avoid that, I have introduced a small delay before the call to `refresh` in `on_release`:

```
def on_release(self):
    print('Button released')
    # uncomment if loop enabled in on_press()
    # self._root().after_cancel(self.button_held_job)
    self.after(1, self.refresh)
```

On my computer at least, this 1 ms delay is enough to get the updated value.